# VB6 Boolean - Nothing literal

Tags: vb6

If you set a boolean to nothing in VB.NET (I know this is wrong because booleans have the literals: TRUE and FALSE), then the value of the boolean becomes false i.e. :

```
Public Sub Page_Load(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim boolTest As Boolean
boolTest = Nothing 'boolTest becomes FALSE

End Sub
```

However, in VB6 you get a compile time error i.e. invalid use of object.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

This is because Nothing is an object in VB6.  VB.Net seems to think lots of things are objects one way or another, but VB6 has stronger typing in this case.

Comment: +1. VB6 makes a distinction between objects and other variables. VB.Net doesn't. VB.Net also allows value types to be set to Nothing, which resets them to their default values. False is the default value for a Boolean.